# How to match exact word anywhere in string with PHP regexp

Tags: php, regex

I want to find out if user has used the words `admin` or `username` anywhere in their possible username string.

So if user wants to use `admin`, or `I am admin`, or `my admin name` or `my username`, as their username, I want my regexp to detect it. If he uses `adminmember` I can live with that, don't detect it. I also want detection to be case insensitive.

So far I got this, but it is not really working as I thought, since it will detect words that it shouldn't:

`/^[admin|username]+$/i`

This will match even `adm`, and it shouldn't. I have tried with word boundaries, but I couldn't make it work either, maybe I did something wrong. As you can see in my question I would like to detect word admin anywhere in the string, but if it is a part of some word I can skip it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: username will be with spaces. hope its without spaces

Comment: @Venkatraman I am allowing spaces, why do you think it is bad ?

Comment: if its user display name is fine but if its for user unique identification is not good in DB Level indexing

Comment: ID is for user unique identification

Comment: then fine. check my answer for keeping the admin, username in the array in future. its bit easy to add one more element or get those list of words from external file / api. with working PHP Fiddle URL

Comment: Why do you have the `i` modifier if you want it to be case-sensitive? Do you misunderstand what that modifier does, or did you specify that incorrectly?

Comment: @Barmar I wrote it badly, I thought case-insensitive. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square brackets in a regexp are not for grouping, they're for specifying character classes; grouping is done with parentheses. You don't want to anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`, because that will only match at the beginning and end of the string; you want to use `\b` to match word boundaries.

```
/\b(admin|username)\b/i
```

Comment: Yeah, this works exactly as I want. Thanks for explanation too.

Comment: Author said he wants case-sensitive so you should remove trailing *I*

Answer (score 1):

Just look for words using word boundaries:

```
/\b(?:admin|username)\b/i
```

and if there is a match return error e.g.

```
if (preg_match('/\b(?:admin|username)\b/i', $input)) {
    die("Invalid Input");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet to keep your list of words in `Array`.

```
$input = "im username ";
$spam_words = array("admin", "username");
$expression = '/\b(?:' . implode($spam_words, "|") . ')\b/i';

if (preg_match($expression, $input)) {
  die("Username contains invalid value");
}
else {
  echo "Congrats! is valid input";
}
```

Working Fiddle URL:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f8e806683c45249338090b49ae9cd001851af49

Answer (score 0):

This might be the pattern that you're looking for:

```
'#(^|\s){1}('. $needle .')($|\s|,|\.){1}#i'
```

Some details depend on the restrictions that you want to apply.

Comment: What question are you answering?